# Render template and I want to the url address change too

Tags: python, django

I from login page render to the admin index page, but the url address did not change, how to change it?

[image]

Code is below:

```
return render(request, 'app_admin/index.html')
```

As a common sense , all we know use render the url address do not change, but I want it change. how can I do that? I do not want to use the redirect, because I will pass data in render. how can I do that?

Comment: provide information on the `urls.py` file that you defined `/login` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the render to change the URL. Django uses the model-view-controller pattern, and the view has nothing to do with the URL. To achieve what you want you will have to redirect the user first, and then render on that route instead.

I see the URL on your page is `/login` so I assume this problem occur when you attempt to log the user in. If you reuse this approach (render upon receive submit form), you will run into problems sooner or later. For example, try to refresh the page you are currently displaying, I think the browser asks you to resubmit the form.

You say that you don't want to redirect because you pass data in the render. This is also an error prone approach. Store information consistently between pages with cookies and sessions. How would you otherwise store the login details when the user navigates the admin panel?

What you ask is not possible. The [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function (with friends) has no option to change the URL.

Comment: Friend, I have a question, if I redirect, then render, how can I pass the request to the render?

Comment: @244boy You should ask a new question with the new view and specify what you are attempting to do. I'm unable to give a good answer to this question here.

Comment: Ok, I will do it, and response you.

Comment: I have open a new post in there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214614/how-can-i-pass-the-request-if-i-redirect-and-then-render-the-template

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a separate `url` if you want to display in browser URL
For this
Add url for a `index.hmtl` and assign `view` to it
on action call just `url` what you specified