# How can I pass the request if I redirect and then render the template

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement, from login page jump to the admin page, you know the URL address should change to the admin page.

If I only use render to admin page, the URL address will not change, so in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191173/render-template-and-i-want-to-the-url-address-change-too/46191316?noredirect=1) I get the OptimusCrime's good answer.

But if I redirect and then render template, I can not pass the request from login page to the admin page.

in the login page's views.py:

```
...
return redirect('/app_admin/index/')
```

in the admin page's views.py:

```
...
return render(request, 'app_admin/index.html') # there the request is None.
```

How can I pass the request to the admin page's views.py?

Comment: You should really consider learning how the HTTP protocol work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at some basic Django tutorials, such as [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#examples), which describes how to create a login handler.

The gist is this:

In the view where the user submit the form, you evaluate the username and/or password. If the submitted the correct information (username and password), then save this information in the session. Redirect the user to the logged in (restricted) area and check the session. If the session has the correct information, then allow the user to view the content, otherwise redirect the user out.

**Simple login logic (illustrative):**

```
def login(request):
    m = Member.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
    if m.password == request.POST['password']:
        # Username and password is correct, save that the user is logged in in the session variable
        request.session['logged_in'] = True
        request.session['username'] = request.POST['password']
        # Redirect the user to the admin page
        return redirect('/app_admin/index/')
    else:
        # Username and/or password was incorrect
        return HttpResponse("Your username and password didn't match.")
```

**Simple admin page logic (illustrative):**

```
def admin_index(request):
    # Make sure that the user is logged in
    if 'logged_in' in request.session and request.session['logged_in']:
        # User is logged in, display the admin page
        return render(
            request, 
            'app_admin/index.html', 
            {'username': request.session['username']}
        ) # You can now use {{ username }} in your view
    # User is not logged in and should not be here. Display error message or redirect the user to the login page
    return HttpResponse("You are not logged in")
```

Note that these are two different views (and URLs), that you have to map up in your [urlpatterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views).

Comment: If I want to use the password in the `/app_admin/index/`, wether I should store the password in the session? or maybe better use the password in the `/login/`.

Comment: You should not use the user password for anything but logging the user in. But you can save whatever information you want in the session variable. See my updated answer where I save the current username.

Comment: I use the password to connect the other application, so I do the connection in the /login/, thank you very much.

Comment: You could sent the password as well, it is just a matter of safety risks and what is considered "good" and "bad". But sure. Hope this solved your problems.